# Working with NavigationView Xamarin

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, navigationview

Hi I have problem with NavigationView . I use this code :

```
        nav = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
        View vie = nav.GetHeaderView(0);
        TextView title1 = vie.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.title1);
        TextView title2 = vie.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.title2);
        ImageView logo_menu = vie.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        title1.Text = MenuLayout.text1;
        title1.TextSize = MenuLayout.text1_size;
        title1.SetTextColor(MenuLayout.text1_color);
        title2.Text = MenuLayout.text2;
        title2.TextSize = MenuLayout.text2_size;
        title2.SetTextColor(MenuLayout.text2_color);
        logo_menu.SetImageBitmap(MenuLayout.menu_Image);
        vie.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
```

The last line not working , nothing change ... How Can I set background of header Programmatically ? My secend problem is change text and icon items of Navmenu (Can I change when program work ? How override this)